# Triangle inequailty for $L^p$ norm to power $p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces

I would like to prove the sharp estimate for the $L_p$ norm to power $p$ with $1\leq p <\infty$. What is the constant $C$ here:

$$\left\|\sum_{j=1}^Jf_j\right\|^p_p\leq C\sum_{j=1}^J\|f_j\|_p^p$$

By triangle and Jensen inequalities, we have
$$\left\|\frac{1}{J}\sum_{j=1}^Jf_j\right\|^p_p\leq \left(\frac{1}{J}\sum_{j=1}^J\|f_j\|_p\right)^p \leq \frac{1}{J}\sum_{j=1}^J\|f_j\|_p^p$$

Which gives $C = J^{p-1}$. Is this correct? Is this the sharpest inequality possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn) pointed out, the answer is correct. The fact that $C=J^{p-1}$ comes from the particular choice $f_j=1$ for each $j \in  \left\{1,\dots,J \right\}$.